# React returning ruby array as undefined. with backbone model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, reactjs

I am trying to return a bucketlist object, that bucketlist has followers, the bucketlist and it's attributes are coming through, but it's array of followers isn't.  It returns "undefined" when logged in the JS console.

Here is where I am logging it:

```
 var BucketlistShow = React.createClass({
   mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],
   render: function() {
     var bucketlist = this.props.bucketlist;
     var bucketlistName = bucketlist.name;
     var followers = this.props.followers;
     console.log(followers);                                                   

     return(
```

Here is where it is being set in options:

```
class IE.Views.BucketlistShowView extends Backbone.View                           
  initialize: (options) ->                                                        
    @bucketlist = options.bucketlist                                              
    @followers = options.followers                                                

  render: ->                                                                      
    React.render(BucketlistShowFactory({bucketlist: @bucketlist}), $("#bucketlist-
show-wrapper")[0]);
```

And here is where it is being passed:

```
 #bucketlist-show-wrapper
 :javascript
   var bucketlist = #{@bucketlist.to_json}
   var followers = #{@bucketlist.followers.to
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var view = new IE.Views.BucketlistShowVi
       bucketlist: bucketlist,               
       followers: followers
     });
     view.render();
   });
```

I can retrieve the followers everywhere except the view ( the first snippet of code at the top ).

That console.log, along with console.log(bucketlist.followers) are returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys ( and ladies ), I had to create backbone associations for the models.  That was the trick.